# Is it possible to add a column in sharePoint with more than one element and to filter and retrieve separately the elements entered?

Tags: sharepoint

For example, if we create a column "Company name" you can enter 2 companies (ex. BMW and Ford) and then make a filter that retrieves only the BMW entries? Or the only option is to create two columns ("Company name1" and "Company name2")?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has OOB feature for choice filed(You could filter by API also, caml query or rest api(SharePoint 2013 and above version)).

Demo in my local SharePoint 2013.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Lee_MSFT! But I need the row to be able to be divided into two separate elements (one for Ford and the other for BMW) and both to be recoverable.

Comment: But I need a row that can be divided into two separate elements (one for Ford and the other for BMW) within the same column (Company name). And that both Ford and BMW can be retrieved by filtering by the column Company name.